# How do I implement automata for [a-z][.?!][ ]+[A-Z] , using Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I request you to let me know how to complete the program

```
start(q0).
final(q4).

transition(q0,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z],q1).
transition(q1,[.,?,!],q2).
transition(q2,[ ],q3).
transition(q3,[ ],q3).
transition(q3,[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z],q4).
```

Comment: You could next write down which predicate you plan to call and then think about under what conditions that predicate should succeed. It will probably need to refer to `start` and `end` itself and somehow chain `transition`s, so you may need a predicate that combines multiple transitions.

Comment: Correct answer based on the given answer and guidance by CapelliC:

start(q0).
final(q4).

transition(q0,[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z],q1).
transition(q1,[.,?,!],q2).
transition(q2,[' '],q3).
transition(q3,[' '],q3).
transition(q3,['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'],q4).


accept(Atom) :-
    atom_chars(Atom, Chars),
    start(S), accept(Chars, S).

accept([], F) :- final(F).
accept([C|Cs], State) :-
    transition(State, Ts, NextState),
    memberchk(C, Ts),
    accept(Cs, NextState).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to quote spaces and uppercase atoms. Here a snippet to do it:

```
?- transition(q0,L,_),maplist(upcase_atom,L,U),writeq(U).
```

now, after correction to transition(q3,...), your question should be answered:

```
accept(Atom) :-
    atom_chars(Atom, Chars),
    start(S), accept(Chars, S).

accept([], F) :- final(F).
accept([C|Cs], State) :-
    transition(State, Ts, NextState),
    memberchk(C, Ts),
    accept(Cs, NextState).
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I solved it, based on your guidance and answer. I request you, if you can explain how does the code you posted work on each step.